# How to detect if a value is null with javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, match

Receiving data from an API and looking for tecto with match () it happens that in some cases the match () is not correct then it is null and I receive the following error:

**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null**

I try to verify if the match () is null that the data is an empty string but still it returns me the same error.

How could I eliminate the error in the console?

My code:

```
            let text = jsonDesc.plain_text;

            dataOfProduct.description.desc = text; 

            const product = 'Producto:';
            let resultProduct = text.match(new RegExp(product + '\\s(\\w+)', 'i'))[1];

            const model = 'Modelo:';
            let resultModel = text.match(new RegExp(model + '\\s(\\w+)', 'i'))[1];

            if( resultProduct !== null && resultProduct.length > 1){
                dataOfProduct.description.title = resultProduct;
            } else{
                dataOfProduct.description.title = ''
            }

            if( resultModel !== null && resultModel.length > 1 ){
                resultModel.description.model = resultModel;
            } else{
                resultModel.description.model = ''
            }
```

Comment: There issue is that you are attempting to access index 1 of a match when the match itself is null. You need to introduce an intermediate variable and then check to see that it is not null before accessing it's properties.

Comment: Thank you. But before I can only verify if the text is different from null since I need to make the match to verify if I find the word of the constant product then I do not know how I could verify before the match. @JonathanWilson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that if `text` string doesn’t match the regex, then the match function returns null, which does not have a [1] to it. You have to store the result of match in a variable and determine if that is null or not before trying to grab [1].

```
let resultProduct = text.match(new RegExp(product + '\\s(\\w+)', 'i'));
if (resultProduct != null) {
  resultProduct = resultProduct[1];
}
```

If the match found something, then the code goes inside the if and grabs the [1] from it. If it didn’t, then it’s null and doesn’t go into the if and your very next if then checks to see if resultProduct is null, which it is.

You’ll need to do this for both your product match and model match.